# Need help in determining the proper element identification for closing the popuop

Tags: jquery, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I am trying to automate finding flight information at "http:www.kayak.com/flights". However, when the site is accessed, it first displays a popup to enter email address and create an account. This popup needs to be closed before any flight info can be entered in the page. The popup can be closed by clicking on "x" icon on top left. Even though I have been able to identify the location of "x" element based on xpath using firebug, the xpath expression of the icon is unable to find it in Selenium IDE. The xpath expression I have is

```
//div[@class='r9-dialog-closeButton r9-icon-x tighter']
```

Can someone suggest the mistake I may have made in coming up with the xpath expression or suggest an alternate way of identifying this element so that it can be properly located?

Comment: Simply send "ESC" to close the popup

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that on the web-site the close button has an extra space between the `r9-icon-x` and `tighter` classes:

```
<div class="r9-dialog-closeButton r9-icon-x  tighter"></div>
                                        HERE^
```

I would just use [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) to avoid issues like this one:

```
//div[contains(@class, "r9-dialog-closeButton")]
```

Or, use *CSS selectors*:

```
div.r9-dialog-closeButton
```

Comment: Hi alecxe - thanks for answering. That trick is awesome. It works beautifully.

Comment: @HiteshKapur please see if the answer can be accepted. Thanks.